# npm and yarn forever resolving packages

Tags: node.js, networking

I recently arrived to a new house in a friend's house in a different country.

If I connect to the wifi, browsing the internet, listening to music and other activities on the internet work just fine. However, npm and yarn are not working.

I do the following:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init -y
```

If I execute `npm i lodash`, then it is stuck forever in `idealTree:test: sill idealTree buildDeps`.

If I run `yarn add lodash`, then it gets stuck in

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
⠠ lodash
```

If I connect to a hotspot, the installation works just fine. So it would rule out some bad configuration on my laptop (say firewall).

If I run the same commands in my friends laptop (Windows) on the same network, it works just fine. So it would rule out some firewall configuration at the router level.

What can be the issue, how can I debug it?

Running npm with timing:

```
$ npm i lodash --timing
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/tmp/test/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:$HOME/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 5ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 5ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 11ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 6ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the npm version combined with a not so good connection.

Using npm 10 fixes the issue